# Setting Flyout to Main Frame Navigation(Windows 8.1 app store)

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have created login screen using settings flyout control in Windows 8.1 store app. I need to navigate to Mainpage.xaml in case user successfully entered the login credentials.

How can handle parent Frame navigation from Settings Flyout.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can hide the SettingsFlyout and Navigate to the MainPage using Frame Navigation, after the required validation.

[C#]:

```
new SettingsFlyout().Hide();
this.Hide();
(Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
```

Answer (score 0):

Guidance is not to preform navigation from a SettingsFlyout (see “[Inappropriate Use of Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh770544.aspx)” section).  Generally, a Popup is a better option for a login dialog and a popup would allow you to easily navigate to the main page.